# How to open PDF file from macOS SwiftUI app

Tags: pdf, swiftui

I'm wondering how to open PDF file stored in file system from macOS SwiftUI app. I found solution using QuickLook framework [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-preview-files-using-quick-look-and-qlpreviewcontroller) but it's for files stored in app bundle. Is there any easy way how to open file in app associated with file type (PDF for example)? My app is using url to file stored in user's Documents folder.
Thanks.

Based on @lorem_ipsum advice I tried to use QuickLook framework with this code

```
if purchase.document != "" {
    Button("", systemImage: "doc.text")
       documentURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: purchase.document!)
    }.quickLookPreview($documentURL)
}
```

and got this error:
[QLPreviewPanel setDelegate:] called while the panel has no controller - Fix this or this will raise soon.
See comments in QLPreviewPanel.h for -acceptsPreviewPanelControl:/-beginPreviewPanelControl:/-endPreviewPanelControl:.
Attached window is shown[image]

Comment: Just replace the bundle url with your url